# Bootstrap social media buttons won't show

Tags: html, css

The bootstrap social media buttons were showing and now they aren't and I don't know why. Any ideas?

Also when I click the contact button on the menu, the point it jumps to is not lined up with the start of the contact section, it was previously working like the rest of the sections and I can't figure that out either.

link to the [code pen](https://codepen.io/Rob100/pen/YWbAmK?editors=1100)

```
.navbar {
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/***** HOME *****/

#home {
  background: url("http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2016-06-25-1466835058-3172856-DKCWebDesignBanner.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 680px;
}

.home-wrap {
  padding-top: 140px;
}

.home-header {
  font-family: 'Lobster';
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Lobster';
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
}

.home-line {
  border: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 90%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 153, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;  
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: silver;
  color: black;
}

/***** ABOUT *****/
#about{
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.about-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 95px;
}

h3 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: ;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
.about-line {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40%;
}
 .align {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 2em auto;
  text-align: center;
}
  .imga {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 20px;
}

/***** PORTFOLIO *****/

#portfolio {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #EEDFCC;
}

.portfolio-header {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #000;
}
.portfolio-line {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40%;
}

.placeholder-item {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  overflo: hidden;
}

.placeholder-desc {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}

.imgp {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.divider {
  background-color: black;
  height: 3px;
}


/***** CONTACT *****/

#contact {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}
.contact-wrap {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.contact-header {
  font-family: "Oswald";
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.contact-line {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  width: 40%;
}

.contact-wrap {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

input {
  width: 40%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#message {
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#submit-button {
  widh: 10%;
  height: 40px;
}

/***** FOOTER *****/

footer {
  background-color: black;
  height: 40px;
}

.footer-menu {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.footer-menu li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 10px;
}

.footer-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.footer-menu li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 10px;
}

.footer-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
}

 <head> 
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|PT+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<!-- Navigation bar with the help of bootstrap -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Portfolio 1st Attempt</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="home">
  <div class="home-wrap text-center">
    <h1 class="home-header">Personal Portfolio Webpage</h1>
    <h2>Social Media links</h2>
    <hr class="home-line">
    <div>
      <a class="btn btn-default" type="button"  href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-fire"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
           <div id="about">
           <div class="container">
           <div class="about-wrap text-center">
           <h3>Skills</h3>
          <hr class="about-line">
        <div class="align">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5" target="_blank"><img class="imga" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnkqgvjbd/image/upload/v1451679096/html_u7horu.png" alt="HTML5"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets" target="_blank"><img class="imga" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnkqgvjbd/image/upload/v1451679096/css3_v0rzyx.png" alt="CSS3"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/" target="_blank"><img class="imga" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnkqgvjbd/image/upload/v1451679097/rails_jusgqs.png" alt="Rails"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank"><img class="imga" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnkqgvjbd/image/upload/v1451679096/javascript_a2cxa4.png" alt="Javascript" ></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <a href="http://jquery.com/" target="_blank"><img class="imga" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnkqgvjbd/image/upload/v1451679096/jQuery_uy0yu0.gif" alt="jQuery"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <a href="https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/" target="_blank"><img class="imga" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnkqgvjbd/image/upload/v1451679097/ruby_t0scub.png" alt="Ruby"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/" target="_blank"><img class="imga" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnkqgvjbd/image/upload/v1451679096/bootstrap_xfpqre.png" alt="Bootstrap"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL" target="_blank"><img class="imga" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnkqgvjbd/image/upload/v1451679097/sql_mnbnrc.png" alt="SQL"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
</div>
  <div id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="portfolio-header text-center">PORTFOLIO</h1>
  <hr class="portfolio-line">
    <div class="placeholder-box">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="placeholder-item">
            <a href="#"><img class="imgp" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="project"></a>
            <p class="placeholder-desc"> Placeholder</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="placeholder-item">
            <a href="#"><img class="imgp" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="project"></a>
            <p class="placeholder-desc"> Placeholder</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="placeholder-item">
            <a href="#"><img class="imgp" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="project"></a>
            <p class="placeholder-desc"> Placeholder</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="placeholder-item">
            <a href="#"><img class="imgp" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="project"></a>
            <p class="placeholder-desc"> Placeholder</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="placeholder-item">
            <a href="#"><img class="imgp" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="project"></a>
            <p class="placeholder-desc"> Placeholder</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="placeholder-item">
            <a href="#"><img class="imgp" src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="project"></a>
            <p class="placeholder-desc"> Placeholder</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="contact-wrap text-center">
      <h1 class="contact-header">CONTACT</h1>
      <hr class="contact-line">
      <form method="post" action="#">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Enter your name here"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@example.com" required="required"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea id="message" name="message" required="required" data-minlength="20"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit-button" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <ul class="footer-menu">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Help much appreciated,

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forget add `font-awesome` css

```
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXEjbB?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks, I thought I just had to add bootstrap in the code pen settings where quick links are added.

Comment: Any idea why my contact page doesn't line up with the start of the contact section correctly? I don't know how it happened, it was working then wasn't, I don't remember changing anything

Comment: Depending on how big your screen is depends where the browser will select as the contact top point. If the contact section is smaller than the available screen area and due to there being nothing underneath, the browser will ensure that the available browser area is filled. Which can mean showing content above the referenced area

Comment: @Corporalis Thanks. Ah that explains correctly when I resize the window to make it smaller! Cool I fixed my just adding some padding.

Comment: No problem, glad to help